# Why is Datadog agent not sending some of the configured metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, datadog

I have Datadog agent running inside Kubernetes cluster. It connects to JMX endpoint on another container and reads metrics from it using custom config file. Most of the metrics are sent as expected, however, some of them are simply missing.

I can connect to agent container via 'kubectl exec..' and confirm that those metrics are in config, and I also don't see any warnings/errors in agent logs.

What could be the issue, where should I look?

Comment: Just checking, but are there values for those metrics to be reported?